# How can I handle operations over many different types in my DSL?

Tags: haskell, dsl, typeclass

Suppose Haskell is to be used to implement an interpreter for a domain specific language. The DSL has a large number of type, represented as data constructors, and a large number of binary expressions. A naive first attempt would be a type class `BinaryOps` encapsulating all binary operations over `MyType` in the DSL:

```
data MyType = A String
            | B Integer
            | C Bool
            | D Double
         {- | E .. Z -}

class BinaryOps a where
    f :: a -> a -> a
    g :: a -> a -> a
    h :: a -> a -> a
    j :: a -> a -> a
    {- many more binary ops -}

instance BinaryOps MyType where
    f (A s1) (A s2) = {- Haskell expression on s1 and s2 -}
    f (A s1) (B s2) = {- ... -}
    f (B s1) (D s2) = {- ... -}
    f _ _ = error "f does not support argument types"

    g (D s1) (A s2) = {- Haskell expression on s1 and s2 -}
    g (D s1) (C s2) = {- ... -}
    g _ _ = error "g does not support argument types"

    h (B s1) (B s2) = {- Haskell expression on s1 and s2 -}
    h (B s1) (C s2) = {- ... -}
    h (B s1) (D s2) = {- ... -}
    h (C s1) (B s2) = {- ... -}
    h (D s1) (C s2) = {- ... -}
    h (D s1) (D s2) = {- ... -}
    h _ _ = error "h does not support argument types"
```

The DSL will have many binary expressions, and many built-in types. The solution above won't scale particularly well: The class definition will be large, and the number of "unsupported" ill-typed combinations of DSL types will grow (the `error` calls).

Is there a more elegant way to use type classes for interpreting the binary expressions in the DSL? Or indeed, is there something like GADTs that provides a more scalable solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't model the operations as an ADT as well? It would probably be much easier to type-restrict the construction of expression representations and interpret them than checking the validity of arguments in the interpretation function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you're using a typeclass in the first place. What does a typeclass gain you over just having normal functions?

Just define binary operators as, well, Haskell binary operators which are just normal functions:

```
f :: MyType -> MyType -> MyType
f = ...
```

Since all your DSL types are in `MyType`, there's no reason to use a typeclass.

### Packing and Unpacking

Of course, this still doesn't solve your `error` problem. One approach I've taken in the past is to use typeclasses to define ways to "pack" and "extract" primitive types into your DSL:

```
class Pack a where
  pack :: a -> MyType

class Extract a where
  extract :: MyType -> a
```

Here's what the instance for `String` would look like:

```
instance Pack String where pack = A
instance Extract String where
  extract (A str) = str
  extract _       = error "Type error: expected string!"
```

The `Extract` class can deal with error handling for incompatible types.

This lets you uniformly "lift" functions into your DSL:

```
-- Lifts binary Haskell functions into your DSL
lift :: (Extract a, Extract b, Pack c) => (a -> b -> c)
          -> MyType -> MyType -> MyType
lift f a b = pack $ f (extract a) (extract b)
```

If you make `MyType` an instance of `Pack` and `Extract`, this will work for both purely Haskell functions *and* functions aware of your DSL. That said, the aware functions will just get some sort of `MyType` and will have to deal with it manually, calling `error` if their `MyType` argument isn't what they expected.

So this solves your `error` problem for functions you can write in straight Haskell but not really for ones that depend on `MyType`.

### Error Handling

Using `pack` is also nice because it's pretty straightforward to switch to a better error-handling mechanism than `error`. You would just switch the type of `extract` (or even `pack`, if appropriate). Maybe you could use:

```
class Extract a where
  extract :: MyType -> Either MyError a
```

and then fail with `Left (TypeError expected got)` which would let you write nice error messages.

This would also let you easily combine multiple primitive functions into "cases" at the `MyType` level. The basic idea is that we combine multiple liftable functions into a single `MyType -> MyType -> MyType` and internally we just use the first one that doesn't give us an error. This can also give us some pretty looking syntax :).

Here's the relevant code:

```
type MyFun = MyType -> MyType -> Either MyError MyType

(|:) :: (Extract a, Extract b, Pack c) => MyFun -> (a -> b -> c) -> MyFun
(f |: option) a b = case f a b of
  Right res -> return res
  Left err  -> (lift option) a b 

match :: MyFun
match _ _ = Left EmptyFunction

test = match |: (\ a b -> a ++ b :: String)
             |: (\ a b -> a || b)
```

Unfortunately, I had to add a `:: String` type signature because it was ambiguous otherwise. The same would happen if I use `+`, since it doesn't know what kind of number to rely on.

Now `test` is a function which works correctly on two `A`s or two `B`s and gives an error otherwise:

```
*Main> test (A "foo") (A "foo")
Right (A "foofoo")
*Main> test (C True) (C False)
Right (C True)
*Main> test (A "foo") (C False)
Left TypeError
```

Also note that this would work perfectly happily on *different* types of arguments, like a case which could combine `A` and `B` values.

This means that you can now conveniently recast your `f`, `g`, `h` and so on functions as top-level names in Haskell. Here is how you could define `f`:

```
f :: MyFun
f = match |: \ s1 s2 -> {- something with strings -}
          |: \ s i   -> {- something with a string and an int -}
          |: \ i d   -> {- something with an int and a double -}
          |: {- ...and so on... -}
```

You will sometimes have to annotate some of the values with type signatures because there isn't always enough information to make type inference work properly. This should only come up if you use operations from typeclasses (ie `+`) or use operations with more general types like `++` for strings (`++` can work on *any* lists).

You'd also have to update `lift` to handle the errors properly. This involves changing it to return an `Either` and adding the necessary plumbing. My version looks like this:

```
lift :: (Extract a, Extract b, Pack c) => (a -> b -> c) -> MyFun
lift f a b = fmap pack $ f <$> extract a <*> extract b
```

### Newtypes

This mostly solves your `error` problem by having the `|:` construct check errors for you. The main weakness with this approach is that it won't work very well if you want your DSL to have multiple types that have the same *underlying* Haskell type like:

```
data MyType = A Double
            | B Double
            {- ... -}
```

You could fix this by using `newtype` to create a wrapper for `Double`. Something like this:

```
newtype BDouble = B Double

instance Pack Double where pack = A

instance Pack BDouble where pack = B

-- same for Extract
```

Comment: Nifty use of `match` and `|:` for type-based dispatch.

Comment: Thank you for replying with such a considered response, a nice answer.

Comment: @tikhon-jelvis Given your 2nd version of the `Extract` class definition to incporate error handling, what is the new definition of `lift`? I assume the return type of `lift` would also have to change to `Either MyError MyType` right? Also, are you suggesting that the `test` function is where all binary operations in my DSL would be defined? Moreover, if I want to `test` to take arguments of different types, I would have to annotate a and b with a type, as well as perhaps annotating the expression with a type, in the body to the right of |: ?

Comment: @RobStewart: The idea is to have each function (ie `f`, `g`, `h`) just be top-level functions themselves all with type `MyFun`. Since all the functions are now the same type, you could also put them into a data structure like a Map if you want. I'll add more details to the answer itself where I have better formatting.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Oh... WOW. This `match` implementation is absolutely beautiful. Such an elegant tool for embedding DSLs. The BinaryOps module for my DSL is now far more readable (and aesthetically pleasing). Has you used this kind of implementation in your own projects? I intend on doing so. Thanks!

Comment: @RobStewart: Heh, thanks. I've used `pack` and `unpack` for my own language, which was really handy. But I've never used the `match` thing—I came up with it for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GADT to better encode the semantics of your dsl.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-} 

data MyType a where 
  A :: String -> MyType String
  B :: Integer -> MyType Integer 
  C :: Bool -> MyType Bool
  D :: Double -> MyType Double
```

The problem of assigning a type to your functions arises. Take `f` for example. I can't imagine a function which is polymorphic enough to take two strings, a string and an integer, or an integer and a double, but not a string and a double. You didn't include the semantics so I don't know what it does. So while you would like to do something like this:

```
class BinaryOps r where 
  add :: r Integer -> r Integer -> r Integer
```

or even

```
class BinaryOps r where 
  add :: Num a => r a -> r a-> r a
```

you can't, because `f` is too polymorphic. The best I could think of:

```
class BinaryOps r where 
  f :: FArg a b c => r a -> r b -> r c  

class FArg a b c 
instance FArg String String a  -- a should be the actual output type
instance FArg String Integer a
instance FArg Integer Double a

instance BinaryOps MyType where 
    f (A s1) (A s2) = undefined 
    f (A s1) (B s2) = undefined 
    f (B s1) (D s2) = undefined
```

This isn't a very good solution because `FArg` says nothing about the arguments, the user would then have to look up the definition of the class, if an instance is added to `FArg`, for example `FArg Double Double Double` you will be able to call `f (D 0) (D 0)` and get a runtime pattern match error. My suggestion would be to change the functions to more sensible types; write the functions as monomorphic and implement implicit or explicit casting in your dsl; include the definition of some actual functions so that it is easier to address this issue.