# Reusing patterns in pattern guards or case expressions

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, pattern-guards

My Haskell project includes an expression evaluator, which for the purposes of this question can be simplified to:

```
data Expression a where
    I :: Int -> Expression Int
    B :: Bool -> Expression Bool
    Add :: Expression Int  -> Expression Int  -> Expression Int
    Mul :: Expression Int  -> Expression Int  -> Expression Int
    Eq  :: Expression Int  -> Expression Int  -> Expression Bool
    And :: Expression Bool -> Expression Bool -> Expression Bool
    Or  :: Expression Bool -> Expression Bool -> Expression Bool
    If  :: Expression Bool -> Expression a    -> Expression a -> Expression a

-- Reduces an Expression down to the simplest representation.
reduce :: Expression a -> Expression a
-- ... implementation ...
```

The straightforward approach to implementing this is to write a `case` expression to recursively evaluate and pattern match, like so:

```
reduce (Add x y) = case (reduce x, reduce y) of
                    (I x', I y') -> I $ x' + y'
                    (x', y')     -> Add x' y'
reduce (Mul x y) = case (reduce x, reduce y) of
                    (I x', I y') -> I $ x' * y'
                    (x', y')     -> Mul x' y'
reduce (And x y) = case (reduce x, reduce y) of
                    (B x', B y') -> B $ x' && y'
                    (x', y')     -> And x' y'
-- ... and similarly for other cases.
```

To me, that definition looks somewhat awkward, so I then rewrote the definition using pattern guards, like so:

```
reduce (Add x y) | I x' <- reduce x
                 , I y' <- reduce y
                 = I $ x' + y'
```

I think this definition looks cleaner compared to the `case` expression, but when defining multiple patterns for different constructors, the pattern is repeated multiple times.

```
reduce (Add x y) | I x' <- reduce x
                 , I y' <- reduce y
                 = I $ x' + y'
reduce (Mul x y) | I x' <- reduce x
                 , I y' <- reduce y
                 = I $ x' * y'
```

Noting these repeated patterns, I was hoping there would be some syntax or structure that could cut down on the repetition in the pattern matching. Is there a generally accepted method to simplify these definitions?

**Edit:** after reviewing the pattern guards, I've realised they don't work as a drop-in replacement here. Although they provide the same result when `x` and `y` can be reduced to `I _`, they do not reduce any values when the pattern guards do not match. I would still like `reduce` to simplify subexpressions of `Add` et al.

Comment: For your code itself, the type of reduce is `Expression a -> Expression Int` ?

Comment: This might be a situation to use [uniplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.11/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Operations.html)

Comment: @rampion thanks, I've heard of uniplate but know little about it. I guess now is a good time to dive into generic programming!

Comment: One other thing you could do, though I'm not sure if you want to, is replace your current functions with something like `data Exp a where BinaryOp :: (a->a->a)->(Exp a)->(Exp a)->(Exp a)` etc...

Comment: @guhou A naive [solution](http://lpaste.net/109375).

Comment: I built this a while back using Prisms, which worked alright.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Can you post your Prism solution here ?

Comment: I may if I get some time. I'd do it on my phone now but I'm not certain I can pull if off without a compiler.

Comment: I'm [working on a uniplate solution now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355570/simplifying-a-gadt-with-uniplate)

Comment: @rampion thanks for continuing to look into it, I started playing with uniplate but ran into my own problems with it. I'll keep an eye on your progress to see if it's helpful!

Answer (score 8):

One partial solution, which I've used in a similar situation, is to extract the logic into a "lifting" function that takes a normal Haskell operation and applies it to your language's values. This abstracts over the wrappping/unwrapping and resulting error handling.

The idea is to create two typeclasses for going to and from your custom type, with appropriate error handling. Then you can use these to create a `liftOp` function that could look like this:

```
liftOp :: (Extract a, Extract b, Pack c) => (a -> b -> c) -> 
            (Expression a -> Expression b -> Expression c)
liftOp err op a b = case res of
  Nothing  -> err a' b'
  Just res -> pack res
  where res = do a' <- extract $ reduce' a
                 b' <- extract $ reduce' b
                 return $ a' `op` b'
```

Then each specific case looks like this:

```
Mul x y -> liftOp Mul (*) x y
```

Which isn't too bad: it isn't overly redundant. It encompasses the information that matters: `Mul` gets mapped to `*`, and in the error case we just apply `Mul` again.

You would also need instances for packing and unpacking, but these are useful anyhow. One neat trick is that these can also let you embed functions in your DSL automatically, with an instance of the form `(Extract a, Pack b) => Pack (a -> b)`.

I'm not sure this will work exactly for your example, but I hope it gives you a good starting point. You might want to wire additional error handling through the whole thing, but the good news is that most of that gets folded into the definition of `pack`, `unpack` and `liftOp`, so it's still pretty centralized.

I [wrote up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491228/how-can-i-handle-operations-over-many-different-types-in-my-dsl/22491800#22491800) a similar solution for a related (but somewhat different) problem. It's also a way to handle going back and forth between native Haskell values and an interpreter, but the interpreter is structured differently. Some of the same ideas should still apply though!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is inspired by [rampion's follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355570/simplifying-a-gadt-with-uniplate), which suggests the following function:

```
step :: Expression a -> Expression a
step x = case x of
  Add (I x) (I y) -> I $ x + y
  Mul (I x) (I y) -> I $ x * y
  Eq  (I x) (I y) -> B $ x == y
  And (B x) (B y) -> B $ x && y
  Or  (B x) (B y) -> B $ x || y
  If  (B b) x y   -> if b then x else y
  z               -> z
```

`step` looks at a single term, and reduces it if everything needed to reduce it is present. Equiped with `step`, we only need a way to replace a term everywhere in the expression tree. We can start by defining a way to apply a function inside every term.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

emap :: (forall a. Expression a -> Expression a) -> Expression x -> Expression x
emap f x = case x of
    I a -> I a
    B a -> B a
    Add x y   -> Add (f x) (f y)
    Mul x y   -> Mul (f x) (f y)
    Eq  x y   -> Eq  (f x) (f y)
    And x y   -> And (f x) (f y)
    Or  x y   -> Or  (f x) (f y)
    If  x y z -> If  (f x) (f y) (f z)
```

Now, we need to apply a function everywhere, both to the term and everywhere inside the term. There are two basic possibilities, we could apply the function to the term before applying it inside or we could apply the function afterwards.

```
premap :: (forall a. Expression a -> Expression a) -> Expression x -> Expression x
premap f = emap (premap f) . f

postmap :: (forall a. Expression a -> Expression a) -> Expression x -> Expression x
postmap f = f . emap (postmap f)
```

This gives us two possibilities for how to use `step`, which I will call `shorten` and `reduce`.

```
shorten = premap step
reduce = postmap step
```

These behave a little differently. `shorten` removes the innermost level of terms, replacing them with literals, shortening the height of the expression tree by one. `reduce` completely evaluates the expression tree to a literal. Here's the result of iterating each of these on the same input

```
"shorten"
If (And (B True) (Or (B False) (B True))) (Add (I 1) (Mul (I 2) (I 3))) (I 0)
If (And (B True) (B True)) (Add (I 1) (I 6)) (I 0)
If (B True) (I 7) (I 0)
I 7
"reduce"
If (And (B True) (Or (B False) (B True))) (Add (I 1) (Mul (I 2) (I 3))) (I 0)
I 7
```

#### Partial reduction

Your question implies that you sometimes expect that expressions can't be reduced completely. I'll extend your example to include something to demonstrate this case, by adding a variable, `Var`.

```
data Expression a where
    Var :: Expression Int
    ...
```

We will need to add support for `Var` to `emap`:

```
emap f x = case x of
   Var -> Var
   ...
```

`bind` will replace the variable, and `evaluateFor` performs a complete evaluation, traversing the expression only once.

```
bind :: Int -> Expression a -> Expression a
bind a x = case x of
    Var -> I a
    z   -> z

evaluateFor :: Int -> Expression a -> Expression a
evaluateFor a = postmap (step . bind a)
```

Now `reduce` iterated on an example containing a variable produces the following output

```
"reduce"
If (And (B True) (Or (B False) (B True))) (Add (I 1) (Mul Var (I 3))) (I 0)
Add (I 1) (Mul Var (I 3))
```

If the output expression from the reduction is evaluated for a specific value of `Var`, we can reduce the expression all the way to a literal.

```
"evaluateFor 5"
Add (I 1) (Mul Var (I 3))
I 16
```

#### Applicative

`emap` can instead be written in terms of an `Applicative` `Functor`, and `postmap` can be made into a generic piece of code suitable for other data types than expressions. How to do so is described in [this answer to rampion's follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25389564/414413).