# Simplifying a GADT with Uniplate

Tags: haskell, gadt, uniplate

I'm trying to answer [this stackoverflow question, using `uniplate` as I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311781/reusing-patterns-in-pattern-guards-or-case-expressions#comment39456277_25311781), but [the only solution I've come up with so far](https://gist.github.com/rampion/44deb2f2ca9e2b53f2b8) is pretty ugly.

This seems like a fairly common issue, so I wanted to know if there was a more elegant solution.

Basically, we've got a GADT which resolves to either `Expression Int` or `Expression Bool` (ignoring `codataIf = If (B True) codataIf codataIf`):

```
data Expression a where
    I :: Int -> Expression Int
    B :: Bool -> Expression Bool
    Add :: Expression Int  -> Expression Int  -> Expression Int
    Mul :: Expression Int  -> Expression Int  -> Expression Int
    Eq  :: Expression Int  -> Expression Int  -> Expression Bool
    And :: Expression Bool -> Expression Bool -> Expression Bool
    Or  :: Expression Bool -> Expression Bool -> Expression Bool
    If  :: Expression Bool -> Expression a    -> Expression a -> Expression a
```

And (in my version of the problem) we want to be able to evaluate the expression tree from the bottom-up using a simple operation to combine leaves into a new leaf:

```
step :: Expression a -> Expression a
step = \case
  Add (I x) (I y)   -> I $ x + y
  Mul (I x) (I y)   -> I $ x * y
  Eq (I x) (I y)    -> B $ x == y
  And (B x) (B y)   -> B $ x && y
  Or (B x) (B y)    -> B $ x || y
  If (B b) x y      -> if b then x else y
  z                 -> z
```

I had some difficulty using `DataDeriving` to derive `Uniplate` and `Biplate` instances (which maybe should have been a red flag), so 
I rolled my own `Uniplate` instances for `Expression Int`, `Expression Bool`, and `Biplate` instances for `(Expression a) (Expression a)`, `(Expression Int) (Expression Bool)`, and `(Expression Bool) (Expression Int)`.

This let me come up with these bottom-up traversals:

```
evalInt :: Expression Int -> Expression Int
evalInt = transform step

evalIntBi :: Expression Bool -> Expression Bool
evalIntBi = transformBi (step :: Expression Int -> Expression Int)

evalBool :: Expression Bool -> Expression Bool
evalBool = transform step

evalBoolBi :: Expression Int -> Expression Int
evalBoolBi = transformBi (step :: Expression Bool -> Expression Bool)
```

But since each of these can only do one transformation (combine `Int` leaves or `Bool` leaves, but not either), they can't do the complete simplification, but must be chained together manually:

```
λ example1
If (Eq (I 0) (Add (I 0) (I 0))) (I 1) (I 2)
λ evalInt it
If (Eq (I 0) (I 0)) (I 1) (I 2)
λ evalBoolBi it
If (B True) (I 1) (I 2)
λ evalInt it
I 1
λ example2
If (Eq (I 0) (Add (I 0) (I 0))) (B True) (B False)
λ evalIntBi it
If (Eq (I 0) (I 0)) (B True) (B False)
λ evalBool it
B True
```

My hackish workaround was to define a `Uniplate` instance for `Either (Expression Int) (Expression Bool)`:

```
type  WExp = Either (Expression Int) (Expression Bool)

instance Uniplate WExp where
  uniplate = \case
      Left (Add x y)    -> plate (i2 Left Add)  |* Left x  |* Left y
      Left (Mul x y)    -> plate (i2 Left Mul)  |* Left x  |* Left y
      Left (If b x y)   -> plate (bi2 Left If)  |* Right b |* Left x  |* Left y
      Right (Eq x y)    -> plate (i2 Right Eq)  |* Left x  |* Left y
      Right (And x y)   -> plate (b2 Right And) |* Right x |* Right y
      Right (Or x y)    -> plate (b2 Right Or)  |* Right x |* Right y
      Right (If b x y)  -> plate (b3 Right If)  |* Right b |* Right x |* Right y
      e                 -> plate e
    where i2 side op (Left x) (Left y) = side (op x y)
          i2 _ _ _ _ = error "type mismatch"
          b2 side op (Right x) (Right y) = side (op x y)
          b2 _ _ _ _ = error "type mismatch"
          bi2 side op (Right x) (Left y) (Left z) = side (op x y z)
          bi2 _ _ _ _ _ = error "type mismatch"
          b3 side op (Right x) (Right y) (Right z) = side (op x y z)
          b3 _ _ _ _ _ = error "type mismatch"

evalWExp :: WExp -> WExp
evalWExp = transform (either (Left . step) (Right . step))
```

Now I can do the complete simplification:

```
λ evalWExp . Left $ example1
Left (I 1)
λ evalWExp . Right $ example2
Right (B True)
```

But the amount of `error` and wrapping/unwrapping I had to do to make this work just makes this feel inelegant and wrong to me.

Is there a *right* way to solve this problem **with `uniplate`**?

Comment: The ``Expression`` type you're using can be expressed without the GADTs, at which point the solution is much simpler. Is there a specific need for GADTs in your AST?

Comment: Stephen Diehl: the non-GADT versions I can think of seem verbose. What are you thinking of?

Comment: Like for instance why the GADT over a closed datatype like: ``data Expr = I Int | B Bool | Add Expr Expr ...``?

Comment: Stephen Diehl: but that allows  the illegal expression `Add (B True) (B True)` which the GADT doesn't

Comment: Well javascript also supports adding up nonsense, so I do not see why this would be bad ;)

Comment: @ThreeFx Hehehe. Folk should watch Gary Bernhardt's Wat?! talk if they haven't already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a right way to solve this problem with uniplate, but there is a right way to solve this problem with the same mechanism. The uniplate library doesn't support uniplating a data type with kind `* -> *`, but we can create another class to accommodate that. Here's a little minimal uniplate library for types of kind `* -> *`. It is based on the current git version of `Uniplate` that has been changed to use `Applicative` instead of `Str`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Identity

class Uniplate1 f where
    uniplate1 :: Applicative m => f a -> (forall b. f b -> m (f b)) -> m (f a)

    descend1 :: (forall b. f b -> f b) -> f a -> f a
    descend1 f x = runIdentity $ descendM1 (pure . f) x

    descendM1 :: Applicative m => (forall b. f b -> m (f b)) -> f a -> m (f a)
    descendM1 = flip uniplate1

transform1 :: Uniplate1 f => (forall b. f b -> f b) -> f a -> f a
transform1 f = f . descend1 (transform1 f)
```

Now we can write a `Uniplate1` instance for `Expression`:

```
instance Uniplate1 Expression where
    uniplate1 e p = case e of
        Add x y -> liftA2 Add (p x) (p y)
        Mul x y -> liftA2 Mul (p x) (p y)
        Eq  x y -> liftA2 Eq  (p x) (p y)
        And x y -> liftA2 And (p x) (p y)
        Or  x y -> liftA2 Or  (p x) (p y)
        If  b x y -> pure If <*> p b <*> p x <*> p y
        e -> pure e
```

This instance is very similar to the `emap` function I wrote in [my answer to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25370450/414413), except this instance places each item into an `Applicative` `Functor`. `descend1` simply lifts its argument into `Identity` and `runIdentity`'s the result, making `desend1` identical to `emap`. Thus `transform1` is identical to `postmap` from the previous answer.

Now, we can define `reduce` in terms of `transform1`.

```
reduce = transform1 step
```

This is enough to run an example:

```
"reduce"
If (And (B True) (Or (B False) (B True))) (Add (I 1) (Mul (I 2) (I 3))) (I 0)
I 7
```

Comment: Nice. It's a bit of a letdown for me, because I intended to post this exact same solution, but then I compulsively tried to implement all of the uniplate API in this lens style, and found out that `holes` and `contexts` cannot be done. So I postponed posting my answer, until I sorted out that issue (and I sorted it out: we need a classic-style `uniplate` that returns lists of children indexed by a type-level list of the type indices of the children).

Comment: I'd guess that you can do `holes` and `contexts` two ways. In one way, you'd lose all the type information about the contained type. In the other you'd require a constraint on `f`. `Typeable1 f, forall a. Typeable f a` should be more than adequate.

Comment: I mean, it's not possible to implement a `holes` returning even existentially quantified types in the lens style, without demanding `Typeable1`, while this is quite possible with a uniplate style implementation. [Here's the source](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/2732f0432ec50500d880). As a side note, with GADTs it's fine most of the time with just existentials (and without `Typeable`), because the type information is usually available from the GADT constructors.

Comment: I have a working `holes1` right now. You defined exactly the same type for `Hole` that I initially did. The trick is to recognize that the return from the function isn't necessarily in `f`. `data Hole f a where Hole :: f b -> (f b -> a) -> Hole f a`

Comment: I asked and answered another question for how to define `holes` and `contexts`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393870/how-can-holes-and-contexts-be-implemented-for-higher-kinded-types-in-a-lens-styl