# How can holes and contexts be implemented for higher-kinded types in a lens style uniplate library?

Tags: haskell, gadt, uniplate

András Kovács proposed this question [in response to an answer to a previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355570/simplifying-a-gadt-with-uniplate/25389564#comment39600628_25389564)

In a lens-style uniplate library for types of kind `* -> *` based on the class

```
class Uniplate1 f where
    uniplate1 :: Applicative m => f a -> (forall b. f b -> m (f b)) -> m (f a)
```

analogous to the class for types of kind `*`

```
class Uniplate on where
    uniplate :: Applicative m => on -> (on -> m on) -> m on
```

is it possible to implement analogs to `contexts` and `holes`, which both have the type `Uniplate on => on -> [(on, on -> on)]` without requiring `Typeable1`?

It's clear that this could be implemented in the old-style of the uniplate library which used `Str` to represent the structure of the data by returning a structure with a type-level list of the types of the children.

A hole could be represented by the following data type, which would replace `(on, on -> on)` in the signatures for `contexts` and `holes`

```
data Hole f a where
    Hole :: f b -> (f b -> f a) -> Hole f a

holes :: Uniplate1 f => f a -> [Hole f a]
...
```

However, it is unclear if there is an implementation for `holes` which doesn't require `Typeable1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested type `Hole` is needlessly restrictive in the return type of the function. The following type can represent everything the former `Hole` represents, and more, without loss of any type information.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Hole f a where
    Hole :: f b -> (f b -> a) -> Hole f a
```

If we need to have a return type of `f a`, we can use `Hole f (f a)` to represent it. Since we will be using `Hole`s a lot, it'd be nice to have a few utility functions. Because the return type of the function in `Hole` is no longer constrained to be in `f`, we can make a `Functor` instance for it

```
instance Functor (Hole f) where
    fmap f (Hole b g) = Hole b (f . g)
```

`contexts1` can be written for either version of `Hole` by replacing the constructors for tuples in the uniplate library's `contexts` with `Hole`:

```
contexts1 :: Uniplate1 f => f a -> [Hole f (f a)]
contexts1 x = Hole x id  : f (holes1 x)
    where    
        f xs = [ Hole y (ctx . context)
               | Hole child ctx <- xs
               , Hole y context <- contexts1 child]
```

`holes1` is trickier, but can still be made by modifying `holes` from the `uniplate` library.  It requires a new `Replace1` `Applicative` `Functor` that uses `Hole` instead of a tuple. Everyhwere the second field of the tuple was modified by `second (f .)` we replace with `fmap f` for the `Hole`.

```
data Replace1 f a = Replace1 {replaced1 :: [Hole f a], replacedValue1 :: a}

instance Functor (Replace1 f) where
    fmap f (Replace1 xs v) = Replace1 (map (fmap f) xs) (f v)

instance Applicative (Replace1 f) where
    pure v = Replace1 [] v
    Replace1 xs1 f <*> Replace1 xs2 v = Replace1 (ys1 ++ ys2) (f v)
        where ys1 = map (fmap ($ v)) xs1
              ys2 = map (fmap (f)) xs2

holes1 :: Uniplate1 f => f a -> [Hole f (f a)]
holes1 x = replaced1 $ descendM1 (\v -> Replace1 [Hole v id] v) x
```

`decendM1` is defined in [the preceding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25389564/414413). `Replace` and `Replace1` can be unified; how to do so is described after the examples.

Let's try some examples in terms of the code in the previous question. The following utility functions on `Hole`s will be useful.

```
onHole :: (forall b. f b -> c) -> Hole f a -> c
onHole f (Hole x _) = f x

inHole :: (forall b. f b -> f b) -> Hole f a -> a
inHole g (Hole x f) = f . g $ x
```

#### Examples

We'll use the following example data and function, based on the code from the preceding questions:

```
example = If (B True) (I 2 `Mul` I 3) (I 1)

zero :: Expression b -> Expression b
zero x = case x of
    I _ -> I 0
    B _ -> B False
    Add _ _ -> I 0
    Mul _ _ -> I 0
    Eq  _ _ -> B False
    And _ _ -> B False
    Or  _ _ -> B False
    If  _ a _ -> zero a
```

Holes

```
sequence_ . map (onHole print) . holes1 $ example

B True
Mul (I 2) (I 3)
I 1
```

Contexts

```
sequence_ . map (onHole print) . contexts1 $ example

If (B True) (Mul (I 2) (I 3)) (I 1)
B True
Mul (I 2) (I 3)
I 2
I 3
I 1
```

Replacement of each context

```
sequence_ . map print . map (inHole zero) . contexts1 $ example

I 0
If (B False) (Mul (I 2) (I 3)) (I 1)
If (B True)  (I 0)             (I 1)
If (B True)  (Mul (I 0) (I 3)) (I 1)
If (B True)  (Mul (I 2) (I 0)) (I 1)
If (B True)  (Mul (I 2) (I 3)) (I 0)
```

#### Unifying Replace

The `Replace` `Applicative` `Functor` can be refactored so that it doesn't know about the type of holes for either `Uniplate` or `Uniplate1`, and instead only knows that the hole is a `Functor`. Holes for `Uniplate` were using the type `(on, on -> a)` and essentially using `fmap f = second (f .)`; this is the composition of the `(on, )` and `on->` functors.

Instead of grabbing `Compose` from the transformers library, we'll make a new type for a `Hole` for `Uniplate`, which will make the example code here be more consistent and self-contained.

```
data Hole on a = Hole on (on -> a)

instance Functor (Hole on) where
    fmap f (Hole on g) = Hole on (f . g)
```

We'll rename our `Hole` from before to `Hole1`.

```
data Hole1 f a where
    Hole1 :: f b -> (f b -> a) -> Hole1 f a

instance Functor (Hole1 f) where
    fmap f (Hole1 b g) = Hole1 b (f . g)
```

`Replace` can drop all knowledge of either type of hole.

```
data Replace f a = Replace {replaced :: [f a], replacedValue :: a}

instance Functor f => Functor (Replace f) where
    fmap f (Replace xs v) = Replace (map (fmap f) xs) (f v)

instance Functor f => Applicative (Replace f) where
    pure v = Replace [] v
    Replace xs1 f <*> Replace xs2 v = Replace (ys1 ++ ys2) (f v)
        where ys1 = map (fmap ($ v)) xs1
              ys2 = map (fmap (f)) xs2
```

Both `holes` and `holes1` can be implemented in terms of the new `Replace`.

```
holes :: Uniplate on => on -> [Hole on on]
holes x = replaced $ descendM (\v -> Replace [Hole v id] v) x

holes1 :: Uniplate1 f => f a -> [Hole1 f (f a)]
holes1 x = replaced $ descendM1 (\v -> Replace [Hole1 v id] v) x
```